# How to do looping using ListView.builder and for in flutter

Tags: loops, for-loop, listview, flutter, dart

I am trying to loop my data using `for` and `ListView.builder`, here is part of my code

```
Widget listData(Data myList) {
  List<Check> tab = myList.data.listItem;
  List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
  for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    List<User> user= myList.data.listItem[i].detail;
    list.add(Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: user.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text("check= $i");
          }),
    ));
  }
  return Center(child: new Column(children: list));
}
```

I have 6 data..but using that code I always get the first data only... the other data doesn't show up in my screen... is there something that I should do to show my all data using ListView.builder and `for` looping

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a picture of what you achieved so far..that would make it easier to understand your problem easily..

Comment: I have edited my question... tab.length in my code is 3 but I only get first looping and the result is in the picture inside my question

Comment: Where are you calling `listData`..?

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return listData();
  }

Comment: I am calling listData like that.. I am calling it inside my Stateful widget

Comment: Try to give some height to the `Container` that you mentioned in the question..say some 50 or 100.. not sure if it works.. just give it a try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider giving some height to the `Container` say some 50 or 100..that will solve your issue..